# How to set the height to 100% of the page?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to expand my div all the way from top to bottom even thought I don't have enough elements inside my div.

I have set CSS like

```
#content{
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
    display:block;
    height:100%
    background-color:red;
}
```

my html

```
<div id='content'>
    just a little bit of contents here.
</div>
```

I want to see the red background all the way from top to bottom of the page.

How can I do this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can make it work by adding this CSS code:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

**[jsFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/dm7uc/1/)**

Comment: `width: 100%;` isn’t necessary.

Comment: @false, correct. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

```css
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Note that you don’t need to specify units for zeroes.

Comment: @false yes 'px' is not needed here. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your content div, works a treat!

```
height: 100vh;
```

Comment: Neat solution. However the browser support for this method isn't so good (62% overall): http://caniuse.com/viewport-units